# JPA Relationships

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship

If you have a relationship like this :

[image]

- Employee many to one relationship to its supervising Employee
- Employee many to one relationship to its department
- Department one to one to its manager

I would write in the Employee entity:

```
@ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Employee supervisor;
@ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Department department;
```

and in the department

```
@OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Employee manager;
```

I then would create and  set the variables (name, title, salary, supervisor) of employee

Then I would create the department with his variables (name, code)

With the departments created I then can set the department in the employees

And then I can set the manager in department.

With all the variables set I can persist the entity's.  I persist the Employees (because of the relationships the department will be persist also)

I believe this  is the right way to do this?!

Comment: Why don't you do it, and ask a question if it doesn't work?

Comment: You are right. must take care of where an reference should be assigned and where it shuold be null. There is no reference b/w employee Vs manager ?

Comment: Something can "work" but is it the right way too make it work?  Not everything that works will be "right" so ppl with more experience can suggest a correct way to start, so you can build on it to keep everything in "good practice".

Comment: Then write some code, make it work, and submit it to codereview.stackexchange.com. Commenting on invisible code doesn't make much sense. The only thing I can say is that I don't find it logical to persist a manager by persisting one of its employees. A manager should already exist before you assign it an employee. Same for employee-department and employee-supervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While providing Annotation @ManyToOne; also provide annotation @JoinColumn

As right now u are only worried about persisting it will work fine. If later you want updates also to work in same way ; you would have to use CascadeType.ALL or CascadeType.MERGE